# PTIJ: Purim- International Forum Day

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Is it a bigger mitzvah to post and answer questions on Mi Yodeya on Purim (Furim)  because It sounds like Forum?
Would that make Purim International Forum Day?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Mi Yodeya isn't a forum, so no.

Comment: @Scimonster and all of Mi Yodeya, my mistake!       So Sorry!

Comment: Yes, with some minor corrections. First of all, the "bigger mitzvah" -- a d'oraisa according to some opinions -- is reading, not posting; second, it is the Shabbos after Purim, not Purim itself. Third, it can and should be all Fora, not just Mi Yodeya.

Answer (score 3):

[A Funny Thing Happened on the Way to the Forum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Funny_Thing_Happened_on_the_Way_to_the_Forum) - Purim version...

A Persian king falls in love with a Jewish girl. The king wanted to marry the beautiful girl, but the girl didn't want to marry a non-Jewish king. She couldn't tell the king that she was Jewish. So, what to do?

She posted her question on Mi Yodeya. But, apparently it was deleted because it was written in Persian, and some moderator deleted it.

So, if there are any descendants of this girl around reading this, only they would be allowed to post on this site on "Furim".

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mean International *frum* day, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

Some have a minhag to post on forums during Purim because of the fact that you can read it as furim or fourum. <sub>(source needed)</sub>

But there is no Minhag to post on Mi Yodea, as [Stack Exchange sites are not forums](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110/375663)