# PTIJ Rabbi Eleazer of Worms

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Rabbi Eleazar Rokeach of Worms was a leading talmudist and the author of the
Sefer ha rokeah, which has some fascinating passages regarding teshuvah. I wonder though, is one permitted to serve as a rabbi to animals, particularly non-kosher ones like worms? If not, is this why he had such sharp insight into teshuvah?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Same question can be asked on Rashi.

Comment: "Worms" is actually pronounced "forums." He's the rabbi of Mi Yodeya (or at least was before Purim.)

Comment: I should have also noted that "forums" is actually pronounced "Purim" (as we have learned on mi.yodeya https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89694/ptij-purim-international-forum-day) ...making this guy the Purim Rov https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/80633/1516

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Rav Eleazar of Worms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleazar_of_Worms) was actually [David Hamelech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David)'s Rabbi, as he is known as "The Worm" in Tehillim 22:7:

> [וְאָנֹכִי תוֹלַעַת וְלֹא אִישׁ](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9B%D7%91_%D7%96)

The plural "worms" presumably refers to the rest of David's family, who were born to him.

I'm going to stop short of saying why this is directly [related to insight into Teshuva](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%95%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%A2).

**P.S. You have to upvote this answer because I quoted [Tehillim 22](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86156/psalms-for-festivals?noredirect=1&lq=1) in a Purim Torah answer...**

Comment: OK, you're not that poor that you have to schnorr for Purim .. I upvoted b/c your answer is clever; not b/c of your suggestion. Happy, now??

Comment: @DanF כל הפושט יד נותנים לו

Comment: One who gives *tzedaka* should give *Dei Machsoro*. Are you still lacking  something?