# PTIJ - Upvoting everyone

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Inspired by the comments to [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/90039/16354):

It is [brought down in Halacha Sefarim](https://www.google.ca/search?client=opera&q=%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F%20%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%98%20%D7%99%D7%93%20%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9C%D7%95&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) that כל הפושט יד נותנים לו, anyone who stretches out a hand, we give to him.  Does this apply to Mi Yodeya as well?  Meaning, do I have to upvote every question and answer written on Purim?  I am specifically looking for Halacha Lemaaseh answers.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Are there really that many people sitting too far away from their computers, or farsighted, that they have to stretch to reach their computer/other device?

Comment: @gary It must be referring to a touchscreen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Devarim 15:8](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9617&st=&pgnum=210) says:

> העבט תעביטנו די מחסורו
>
> Continuously pledge to him sufficient for what he is lacking...

In the linked question, you asked people to upvote your answer, there. I did, and others did. You *schnorred* in that answer, and we responded. But, it seems that you are still lacking something, and this question is proof of that fact! You expect people to upvote your question too! I did that, too.

I looked at Rash"i on the verse I just cited. He says that one is not required to make a person rich.

Well, it seems that this site has placed a daily limit on how many points you can get. I think it's 200. Each person has a limit, too. They can only give you 1 vote per question.

So, I've done my part on this question, at least. You have a maximum of 199 more upvotes to go on this question, assuming that others don't vote on any other of your questions, today.

Even schnorring on this site has its limits.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm required to accept and upvote this now...

Comment: Wait until I schnorr tomorrow. Then, you'll know what to do.

Comment: Btw it's a limit of 200 **rep**. per day.

Comment: די מחסורו means what he's missing. *_I_* deserve several thousand reputation points a day. Reputation for r comments, too ;-)

Comment: @Shokhet On Purim, I have a few too many shcnorrers around. I know I'm supposed to give to everyone that comes by, but, when I run  out of cash, myself, all I can give them is a smile and a "rain check". Now, you come along and schnorr, too! What's worse is I can only guess at what you're missing. A new *shechita* knife, perhaps? Please send me the bill; I'll see what I can do before the end of the day.